# Protractor test - Failed: javascript error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to execute protractor test but without success. I get below error message. Any idea why I am getting this error?

I have installed nodejs, npm and protractor correctly.

```
C:\protractor_practice>protractor conf.js
[21:49:06] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:49:06] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
F

Failures:
1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
  Message:
    Failed: javascript error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=homepage&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.7.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A168%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A453%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A478)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A227%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A496%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A76)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A344)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A43%253A27%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A76)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.7.8%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A344)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A168%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A285%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A76)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A344)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A27%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A76)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A344)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A460)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A57)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.Uc.ca.resumeBootstrap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A468)
```

Here is my spec file:

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() { 
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');
    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Here is my conf file:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

[error: [$injector:modulerr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr)